# Linq grab top left corner of points,excluding the first row and first column

Tags: c#, linq

I want to grab the top left and top right of a list of points. I can get the top left and top right like so:

```
var topRightPoint = points.OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).ThenByDescending(pnt => pnt.X).FirstOrDefault();
var topLeftPoint = points.OrderBy(pnt => pnt.X).ThenBy(pnt => pnt.Y).FirstOrDefault();
```

But what I want to grab is the points one row and one column in, as shown by 
 the green circle points:
[image]

I tried doing skips after the orderby and after the thenbydescending/thenby, but it wasn't given the behavior I expected:

```
var topRightPoint = centerPoints.OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).Take(1).OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).ThenByDescending(pnt => pnt.X).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, I don't know how many rows or columns there are. All I'm given as input is an image.

I also want the bottom left and bottom right, one col/row removed. So a generic solution that can work for any point is what I'm shooting for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group the points by one of the coordinates, you can then order and skip the entire first e.g. row and take the next row, order by the other coordinate and take the next to last point:

```
var topRightIn1 = points.GroupBy(p => p.Y).OrderBy(pg => pg.Key).Skip(1).First().OrderByDescending(p => p.X).Skip(1).First();
var topLeftIn1 = points.GroupBy(p => p.Y).OrderBy(pg => pg.Key).Skip(1).First().OrderBy(p => p.X).Skip(1).First();

var bottomRightIn1 = points.GroupBy(p => p.Y).OrderByDescending(pg => pg.Key).Skip(1).First().OrderByDescending(p => p.X).Skip(1).First();
var bottomLeftIn1 = points.GroupBy(p => p.Y).OrderByDescending(pg => pg.Key).Skip(1).First().OrderBy(p => p.X).Skip(1).First();
```

You could wrap this in a function that appends the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` based on which corner you want, but I am not sure it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

To pick highest point use OrderByDescending
To pick lowest point use OrderBy
To pick 1 point less than highest point use OrderByDescending and Skip(1)
To pick 1 point higher than lowest point use OrderBy and Skip(1)

For top right
Highest X - 1, Lowest Y + 1

```
var topRightPoint = centerPoints.OrderByDescending(pnt => pnt.X).Skip(1).First().OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).Skip(1).First();
```

For top left
Lowest X + 1, Lowest Y + 1

```
var topLeftPoint = centerPoints.OrderBy(pnt => pnt.X).Skip(1).First().OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).Skip(1).First();
```

Similarly for bottom left and bottom right